# Setting up MX records for two servers with same hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, subdomain, mx-record

In my DNS records, I have 5 MX records with my hostname being the main domain name of my site `example.com`. These 5 records are `aspmx.google.com`, `alt1.aspmx.google.com`, `alt2.aspmx.google.com`, `alt3.aspmx.google.com`, `alt4.aspmx.google.com` all with hostname `example.com`. I additionally have A records for two extant mail subdomains, `mail.example.com` and `mail1.example.com` (I ought to add some MX records for these).. I wish to make another mail subdomain, let's call it `othermail.example.com` using this guide. In the iRedMail setup, it states that when setting up "first mail domain name" that my mail domain can't be the same as server hostname, so I set it as `example.com` instead of `othermail.example.com`.

[image]

In doing so, have I just caused an issue with my other mail servers? When I add an MX record for `othermail.example.com`, with my hostname set to "@", according to my Digital Ocean, it states:

[image]

where the hostname is `example.com` and the second blacked out bit is `othermail.example.com`. This makes me worry that this means that the other MX records I set for `example.com` are now null and void, as the "mail is handled by" `othermail.example.com`. Can these mail subdomains all coexist together? Have I nullified any other MX records?

Comment: It's not your email domain you need to rename, but the server's hostname. It must never be the same as the email domain as this causes subtle and impossible mail delivery problems.

Comment: So, the original `example.com` email server is at fault? I should not have accounts named `user@example.com` because this would imply the email domain and server's hostname are the same?

Comment: I thought you said your mail domain would be `othermail.example.com`? It is probably not helpful to obfuscate anything here, as I suspect you are confusing both yourself and the rest of us.

Comment: To be clear: `example.com` in my DNS records has 5 MX records with value `aspmx.google.com` then `altN.aspmx.google.com` with N from 1 to 4 each being separate MX records - making 5 overall. I additionally have A records for two extant subdomains for mail: `mail.example.com` and `mail2.example.com`. I wish to make another mail domain, `othermail.example.com` using the guide I linked. It states that the mail domain can't be the same as server hostname, so I put `example.com` as my "first mail domain name". Will this interfere with my `example.com` MX records? Can these mail servers all coexist?

Comment: I've included new information, and will as such edit my post.

Comment: Mails like `local@example.org` can well be delivered to the server with hostname `mail.example.org`. You only need two DNS records for this: `example.org. MX 10 mail.example.org.` and `mail.example.org. A 192.0.2.1`. The same server also could declared serving, say, `other@example.com`, by adding `example.com. MX 10 mail.example.org.`, or any other domain, except just one, guess which one? Right, this server will be unable to serve `something@mail.example.org`, because this mail domain clashes with its hostname.

Comment: In general nothing is bad with server having the same name as mail domain it is serving. This even was always the case back in the 1990's and earier, when email just was invented. But iRedMail doesn't support this, and it has good reasons to not supporting such setup. (A Postfix configuration becomes very fragile and unmaintanable to the point it is better to forbid such setup than permit and face all inherent problems/)

Comment: I see. But can `example.org` be served by two different servers at the same time? One server having users like `local@example.com` and one like `local@mail.example.com`? Basically, I'm just wondering if what I'm doing here will work.

Comment: Please, read my previous comment *very carefully*. An example. **org** domain couldn't have addresses like local@example. **com**. *Whatever* is serving example.org serves addresses like local@example.org, not subdomains. Anything could be that *whatever*, but for that *whatever* mustn't have host name example.org. It may also serve any number of domains, except the one which name equals its own host name, *whatever*. If *whatever* is called mail.example.org, it couldn't serve mail.example.org. If *whatever* is called example. **com**, it could serve both example. **org** and mail.example.org.

Comment: Note, example.org and mail.example.org are distinct mail domains, each on its own full right. Don't get too distracted by the fact they have the same suffix. And any domain can be served by several servers, but none of them should have hostname equals a domain name. example.org could be served by mx1.example.org and mx2.example.com (note different suffix, nothing wrong with this, these are only names) and anything else, even at the same name, you need several MX RRs for that, but then it can't be served by the server called example.org

Comment: I see. So there is no problem to serve domain example.com with two different serves with hostnames mail.example.com and othermail.example.com for instance, because neither of those are called example.com